# Why do I get different exit codes in C# while redirecting output from a batch script?

Tags: c#, process, redirectstandardoutput

When I redirect standardOutput when calling a batch script comparing two files using FC, I get different output compared to when I don't redirect output. What is wrong?

This code will print "0" to my logging window:

```
Process test = new Process();
test.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
test.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c fc /b /a C:\temp\debug\1.txt C:\temp\debug\2.txt";
//test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
//test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
test.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
test.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
test.Start();
test.WaitForExit();
printLog(test.ExitCode.ToString());
return;
```

This code will print "-1" to my logging window:

```
Process test = new Process();
test.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
test.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c fc /b /a C:\temp\debug\1.txt C:\temp\debug\2.txt";
test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
test.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
test.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
test.Start();
test.WaitForExit();
printLog(test.ExitCode.ToString());
return;
```

Comment: Which result do you get running the batch file from the command line?

Comment: .BAT files are called batch scripts, not bat scripts.

Comment: I get exit code 0 when running it from the command line.

Comment: i try it, if file diff then 1 else 0, same result

Comment: Are you sure? Even without redirected standard input? Which OS are you running?

Comment: @Amy - what if you keep them on your utility belt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it.

I needed to redirect standard input along with the standard error and standard output. This code gives me 0 as exit code:

```
Process test = new Process();
test.StartInfo.FileName = "fc.exe";
test.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/b /a C:\temp\debug\1.txt C:\temp\debug\2.txt";
test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
test.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
test.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
test.Start();
test.WaitForExit();
printLog(test.ExitCode.ToString());
return;
```

If you write FC w/o arguments in a cmd bash, you will get -1 as exit code.

Comment: do you know what is the rational behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

A 0 returned should indicate success and anything else is generally failure.  But it appears in this program the following is true:

> The return codes (ERRORLEVEL) for FC appear to be 0 for same, 1 for 
>   different, 2 for file not exists.

[Link to Source](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/169206-46-check-blank-file)

Answer (score 0):

-1 somtimes means something bad happens. Are you sure the redirection works well? Perhaps FC can't perform it's normal file comparing operations and fails?

Comment: This is my guess aswell. My question is maybe why something could go wrong because of the redirected output?

Comment: Try reading the output and error streams, and find out what's written there. Chances are you'll get some info.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I have a stupid command line app, `setcc.exe` that does nothing but set the condition code (exit code) to the specified value:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace setCC
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main( string[] args )
        {
            if ( args.Length == 0 ) throw new ArgumentException( "Required Argument is missing" ) ;
            int  cc      ;
            bool isValid = int.TryParse( args[0] , out cc ) ;
            if ( !isValid ) throw new ArgumentException( "Required parameter is not a valid number") ;
            return cc ;
        }
    }
}
```

So running the command:

```
`setcc 17`
```

set the condition code (exit code, errorlevel) to 17 (as you might expect).

Using that as my child process (and your example code) I wrote this test harness:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace testHarness
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            IEnumerable<bool> Redirections = new bool[]{ false , true } ;
            foreach ( bool redirecting in Redirections )
            {
                int cc ;
                using ( Process test = new Process() )
                {
                    test.StartInfo.FileName               = "cmd.exe"       ;
                    test.StartInfo.Arguments              = @"/c setcc 17 " ;
                    test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError  = redirecting     ;
                    test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = redirecting     ;
                    test.StartInfo.UseShellExecute        = false           ;
                    test.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow         = true            ;
                    test.Start()  ;
                    test.WaitForExit() ;
                    cc = test.ExitCode ;
                }
                Console.WriteLine( "Redirecting:{0}, cc is {1}" , redirecting , cc ) ;
            }
            return ;
        }
    }
}
```

That does nothing but execute `setcc 17` twice in succession, one with redirection turned off and once with redirection turned on.

I get the output I expect to see:

```
Redirecting:False, cc is 17
Redirecting:True, cc is 17
```

I'd look at what value `fc` is handing back. What do you get if you run the same `fc` command in a command shell window, like the following?

```
c:\> fc /b /a C:\temp\debug\1.txt C:\temp\debug\2.txt
c:\> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

I also wonder why your running `fc` inside a command shell (`cmd.exe`) and spawning two processes instead of just one. `fc.exe` is just a standalone command-line app in `c:\windows\system32`: just execute it directly.

Comment: If I run it in the command shell, I get %ERRORLEVEL% == 0. The same as when running it through C# w/o redirected output. I guess I could have  skipped running it through cmd, I just made the code quick to highlight the problem. What I really want to do is to execute a bat file with a redirected std output. At some point in the bat file, it calls FC and checks the result. If the result is different from zero, execution stops. When I run the BAT file w/o redirected standard output everything is fine. When I run the BAT file with redirected standard output, the BAT file halts at after FC.